# When are particles distinguishable?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, identical-particles

I'm just revisting some basics from statisitical mechanics for an exam. One of the exercises asks the reader to calculate the canoncial partition functions of $N$ harmonic oscillators. How should I know wheather these oscillators are distinguishable or not? Because the result will be different and arguably harder to obtain if they're not. The solution distinguishes between the oscillators, so that for e.g the Eigenvalue $E=\hbar\omega(2+1/2)$ is degenerated (e.g $(2,0...,0)\neq(0,2,0...0)$).

Should I just regard all physical particles (e.g electrons) to be indistinguishable and just take the exercisese with distinguishable particles as artificial questions? In some cases distinguishing between particles leads to non-extensive entropys after all.

Answer (score 0):

Particles (specifically bosons) are distinguishable if any of their degrees of freedom are different. The degrees of freedom include the spatial and temporal degrees of freedom (e.g. spatial and temporal frequencies), and their internal degrees of freedom (spin). For identical (indistinguishable) particles (bosons), all these degrees of freedom must be identical.

Fermions (such as electrons) are always distinguishable. The Pauli exclusion principle (which follows from Fermi-Dirac statistics) does not allow two fermions to be identical.